# org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property with where clause

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am trying to get customers data in database based on condition where status of each customer is **"Actve"** this is the default value at the time of insertion but I am setting it deactivated in some query ultimately I want only those who have status "Active"

**I did this**

```
@Override
    public List<Customer> listCustomers() {

return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from customer).list(); 

}
```

But I am getting all **active and deactivated** customer

Then I did this

```
@Override
    public List<Customer> listCustomers() {

        return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from com.mphasis.bharathbank.bean.customer where status="+"'Active'").list();
    }
```

Here I am getting Exception

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with
>   path [/BharathBank] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested
>   exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property:
>   status of: com.mphasis.bharathbank.bean.Customer [from
>   com.mphasis.bharathbank.bean.Customer as c where c.status=Active]]
>   with root cause org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve
>   property: status of: com.mphasis.bharathbank.bean.Customer [from
>   com.mphasis.bharathbank.bean.Customer as c where c.status=Active]

**Model Customer Class**

```
@Entity(name="customer")
@Table(name="customer")
public class Customer implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy =GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="CustID")
    private int CustID;

    @Column(name="Mobile_No")
    private String mobileno;

    @Column(name="F_Name")
    private String fname;

    @Column(name="L_Name")
    private String lname;

    @Column(name="Email_Id")
    private String emailid;

    @Column(name="DOB")
    private String dob;

    @Column(name="Gender")
    private String gender;


    @Column(name="Acc_No")
    private String accno;

    @Column(name="Pwd")
    private String Pwd;


     @Column(name="present_address")
     private String present_address;

     @Column(name="permanent_address")
     private String permanent_address;

     @Column(name="occupation")
     private String occupation;

     @Column(name="marital_status")
     private String marital_status;

     @Column(name="adhaar_card_no")
     private String adhaar_no;

     @Column(name="pan")
     private String pan;

     @Column(name="Balance")
     private String initial_bal;

     @Column(name="status")
     private String accstatus;

    public String getAccstatus() {
        return accstatus;
    }

    public void setAccstatus(String accstatus) {
        this.accstatus = accstatus;
    }


    public int getCustID() {
        return CustID;
    }

    public void setCustID(int custID) {
        CustID = custID;
    }

    public String getMobileno() {
        return mobileno;
    }

    public void setMobileno(String mobileno) {
        this.mobileno = mobileno;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }

    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }

    public String getEmailid() {
        return emailid;
    }

    public void setEmailid(String emailid) {
        this.emailid = emailid;
    }

    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getAccno() {
        return accno;
    }

    public void setAccno(String accno) {
        this.accno = accno;
    }



    public String getPwd() {
        return Pwd;
    }

    public void setPwd(String pwd) {
        Pwd = pwd;
    }

    public String getPresent_address() {
        return present_address;
    }

    public void setPresent_address(String present_address) {
        this.present_address = present_address;
    }

    public String getPermanent_address() {
        return permanent_address;
    }

    public void setPermanent_address(String permanent_address) {
        this.permanent_address = permanent_address;
    }

    public String getOccupation() {
        return occupation;
    }

    public void setOccupation(String occupation) {
        this.occupation = occupation;
    }

    public String getMarital_status() {
        return marital_status;
    }

    public void setMarital_status(String marital_status) {
        this.marital_status = marital_status;
    }



    public String getAdhaar_no() {
        return adhaar_no;
    }

    public void setAdhaar_no(String adhaar_no) {
        this.adhaar_no = adhaar_no;
    }

    public String getPan() {
        return pan;
    }

    public void setPan(String pan) {
        this.pan = pan;
    }

    public String getInitial_bal() {
        return initial_bal;
    }

    public void setInitial_bal(String initial_bal) {
        this.initial_bal = initial_bal;
    }

    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }
    }
```

Comment: please show your Customer class code

Comment: check  Customer's **c** In `from com.mphasis.bharathbank.bean.customer where status="+"'Active'"`, It is not capitalized

Comment: @shantaram_t see my model class it is not capitalized there also

Comment: @thepaulo added customer class model Please look what's wrong

Comment: customer's c need not to be capitalized since I told you former query in question above is working just added where clause here

Comment: @shantaram_t org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: com.mphasis.bharathbank.bean.customer is not mapped [from com.mphasis.bharathbank.bean.customer where status='Active']

Comment: @shantaram_t thanks done this part I am getting what I want